# Is there a way to limit the number of times per day a user can send a certain type of request?

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

What I'm doing at the moment is creating a row in a table for each Facebook request that gets sent. Then, every time a user opens up the FB friend picker to send a request I make a call to a php file that requests information from that table and returns with a list of the FB user ids of all the people they have sent a request to in the last 24 hours. I do this for each type of request the user can send.

The issue I'm having at the moment is that if the user initiates a request, sends them off to a number of people, and then immediately opens the FB friend picker again the previous request action's records have not yet all been added to our internal table. Thus, the players, if they go fast enough, can send multiple requests to the same FB friends.

Is there a way, on the FB side, to limit this behavior Or is this entirely up to the developer to constrain? For either case, is there a recommended method by which I should achieve this behavior? Thank you.

**Update**

It occurred to me that our DB is keeping multiple requests from being entered on a per-user-per-24-hour period. What I do now is simply allow the second request to be made on the FB side and when the code attempts and fails to enter the second row into our DB it makes a FB Graph call that uses the app's auth_token to delete the request from Facebook itself. This means that it will show up for a moment on the receiving player's request page on Facebook but since it isn't linked with a row in the internal DB the user won't receive any reward for clicking-thru anyway.

Thanks for the suggestions, though, everybody. @Gil Birman I went ahead and accepted your answer since it's perfectly valid, even if it's not what I ultimately used to fix the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Can you not just do this with javascript, hide the fb picker, ajax call to the php and on complete show the picker... You should be doing this anyway to pick up errors in the DB write.

Comment: There is nothing for that exists on FB side, it's up to you how to implement this if you need this functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to solve the lag problem you mentioned, one way would be to disable your send request button via javascript as soon as it is pressed. In your javascript code, instead of immediately displaying the send request dialog via FB.UI, send a json request to your server. Only when the server responds should you display the fb send request dialog. Also, the response that the server sends should include the list of friends to exclude. After the fb request is sent your javascript code should send one more json request to the server to indicate what rows in the database needs to be updated. Only when the server responds this second time should you finally re-enable your send request button.

However, there is no way to actually limit the # number of requests that your user can send. That is, no matter how well you design your javascript/php code, your user could still theoretically invoke the request dialog via the Javascript console to completely bypass your attempts to secure the app.